# STM32F407VG Error: Flash Download failed - "Cortex-M4"

Tags: keil, stm32f4discovery

My STM32F4Discovery board worked well until I flashed it. After that, the board was not connecting to my PC (`unknown device`).

Reading forums, I decided to clear flash memory using (pic. 1)[Flash Loader Demonstrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpLfY.png) And the device began to be determined, but it stopped being programmed. When I click button Debug it crashed. [Keil just doesn't answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtrDj.png) I erased flash memory again. After that I recieved another error [Keil asked .dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z4FN.png) I added ST-LINKIII-KEIL.DLL to "C:\Keil\ARM\STLink\ST-LINKIII-KEIL.DLL" but I recieved another error [ST-LINK USB communication error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62zXc.png)  That my settings of Keil [Debug options and driver setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cSs6.png) [Utilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Abky.png) I use ST-Link Debugger, [with that driver it worked fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA2Je.png) In STM32 ST-LINK_Utility you can see that [STM32 ST-LINK_Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qij7X.png) I tryed to flash it in Keil v4 and Keil v5 - same problems.

Comment: Maybe you have exceeded the allowed program size?

Comment: Thank you for answer, but no. I tried a lot of programs, the last one has for{} cycle just to blink LED.

Comment: Time to reinstall keil, or use something free